# open excel file from spfx onclick

Tags: office-365, excel, spfx

I'm working on a spfx app in reactjs and need to open an excel file. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

now i'm using window.open(d.ServerRelativeUrl, '_blank');
but this downloads the file and i dont want that.

I need it to open in excel app not in browser it is connected with a vsto add-in

Answer (score 3):

You should append the query string `?web=1` to the `ServerRelativeUrl`.

It will open the file in the browser instead of downloading the file.

Modify your method as below:

`window.open(d.ServerRelativeUrl + '?web=1','_blank')`

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that the excel has a vsto addin so i need to open it in excel app.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution at microsoft docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes)

So in my case the answer was : "ms-excel:ofe|ofc|u|https://[yoururl]"

Answer (score 0):

When using that method I still get an alert popup like this (Word shown in image, but same goes for all document types):
[image]

Is there any way to avoid this?
I see in the browser console, that when opening the file directly from the out-of-the-box list view, there is this message:
Launched external handler for 'ms-word:ofe%7C

What is this "external handler" and can it be launched from my SPFx code?